# How can I move unallocated space to extend my root?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, gparted

How can I extend my Ubuntu ext4 partition to use the free unallocated space left after formatting the windows partiton?

See screenshot of my disk detup.

[image]

Comment: First you have to boot from an Ubuntu live USB, then proceed with Gparted, because when you are running Ubuntu, the root partition of Ubuntu is mounted and therefore cannot be modified.

Comment: No, the very first thing before messing up with partitions is backup any important information if there is.